# Feature of ios instance variable

Tags: ios, objective-c

I recently mess up with property and ivar.

One very simple question but could not find answer.

Can I say instance var is strong and atomic ?

Thanks~

Comment: I realised my edit to the question was wrong and I'd confused ivars and properties.. I've rolled it back.

Answer (score 2):

For instance variables containing object references, you can use the __weak or the __strong keyword. Default is __strong. If you also declare a property using the instance variable, this needs to agree with the property.

Instance variables cannot be atomic. Being atomic is not a property of an instance variable, it is a property of the code that is used to access it. Therefore properties can be atomic or nonatomic, but instance variables can't. Note that being atomic isn't particularly useful; that's discussed elsewhere.

Instance variables also cannot be readonly. If you have an instance variable, anyone who can access it can both read it and write it. On the other hand, instance variables can be @private, @protected or @public which properties cannot.

Answer (score 1):

To give a broader answer:

A. ownership qualification (strong, weak, unsafe unretained)

As mentioned, (explicitly) *declared ivars* are strong by default as every other local var. You can change that behavior in the usual way with `__weak` or `__unsafe_unretained`.

If you have an (implicitly or explicitly) *synthesized property* and *no* (explicitly) *declared ivar*, the ivar is synthesized and inherits its ownership qualification from the property, which has an default strong ownership.

If you have an (explicitly) *declared ivar* that is bound to an (implicitly or explicitly) *synthesized property*, the ownership qualification of the property and the ivar shall be the same.

> If a property is synthesized, then the associated instance variable is the instance variable which is named, possibly implicitly, by the @synthesize declaration. If the associated instance variable already exists, then its ownership qualification must equal the ownership of the property; otherwise, the instance variable is created with that ownership qualification.

http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#property-declarations

B. Atomicity

Atomicity has two effects:

- The accessors are synchronized with an object level lock.
- The lifetime of the return value exceeds the lifetime of the receiver.

The first subject is obviously related to control flow, not to ownership, so it has no effect on the ivar and you cannot qualify an ivar with atomicity.

The second subject means that you can imagine that the return value gets two additional messages in MRR:

```
return [[ivar retain] autorelease]
```

ARC respects that convention. However, using ARC the meaning of that is academical in usual code.

Answer (score 0):

An instance variable is `strong` by default for objects, unless you use the `__weak` keyword, in which case it's weak.

It's never atomic unless you arrange to use a thread-locking mechanism when assigning it or accessing it.

Generally it's more convenient to use properties over instance variables.

Answer (score -1):

Properties can be strong and atomic, and because strong and atomic are the default you can specify them like this:

```
@property id name;
```

Instance variables are strong by default but as they do not have accessors you need to do any locking yourself. One of the reasons it is better to use properties rather than access instance variables directly.

Comment: "atomic" is mostly useless for making code thread safe. To be thread safe with accessors you still need to do locking yourself.